# How to call specific Object from ObjectArray

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, maps

Trying to get `e.target.data` from the objects generated. `console.log` displays they have `props` with the `data` value I assigned them with. How are event specific objects called? I need to access the original value and also want to `onClick` delete them. But so far everything i tried, only returns _this2 TypeError (is not a function), or data i tried to pass with the `onClick` handler wasn't passed. `this.props.plz_zwischen`is a simple array of strings and passed from parent Component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class checkBox extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();

        this.state = {
            checkboxState: false
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }
    toggle(e){
        console.log('toggle was triggered');
    }

    render(){

        let miniBox = this.props.plz_zwischen.map(function(a, index){
            return <li key={index} data={a}> <label> {a} </label> <input type="checkbox"  onClick={(e) => this.toggle()} /></li>;
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <ul id="rowlist">
                    {miniBox}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to access the another prop in map, it is always a good idea to abstract it to a separate component

```js
function ListItem(props) {
  return (
    <li>
      <label> {props.data} </label> 
      <input type="checkbox"  onClick={(e) => props.toggle(props.data)} />
    </li>
  );
}

class CheckBox extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checkboxState: false
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }
    toggle(a){
        console.log(a);
    }

    render(){

        let miniBox = this.props.plz_zwischen.map((a, index)=>{
            return <ListItem key={index} data={a} toggle={this.toggle} />;
        });

        return(
            <div>
                <ul id="rowlist">
                    {miniBox}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CheckBox  plz_zwischen={['a','b','c']}/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" />
```

That way you can access the single prop in the child component.

Another way to perform the same thing would be to attach it to the DOM as a custom attribute (since it is a string).

```
<li data-item={a} key={index} data={a}> <label> {a} </label> <input type="checkbox"  onClick={(e) => this.toggle()} /></li>
```

and then in on click:

```
event.target.getAttribute('data-item')
```

Do note that components must begin with capital letters

Comment: Thx. It's working. Going through the code right now.